# SOAP error when trying to get data from MS CRM 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, soap, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a clients CRM server.

The main issue I'm currently facing is that the credentials I can work with have limited permissions to the system. Thus, I cannot use the newer `Xrm` classes.

Therefore I've decided to try a more basic approach:

```
        CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
        token.OrganizationName = "OrganizationName";
        token.AuthenticationType = 0;
        Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy.CrmService service = new Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy.CrmService();
        service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
        service.Url = "http://serverIp/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx"; //I've also tried to use <serverIp>/<OrganizationName>
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");
        string fetch = @"<fetch mapping='logical'><entity name='account'><attribute name='accountid'></entity></fetch>";
        string result = service.Fetch(fetch);
```

However, I get a generic `Server was unable to process the request` with no further information. I've checked the event log on the the CRM server, and found nothing of interest. What could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo error but you don't close the tag attribute:

```
<attribute name='accountid' / >
```

Comment: Oh my... I think my coffee is tainted. It clearly failed me. :( Thanks for spotting the error!